# Find the width of every single item in list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to develope feature which paint the text by syllables (like [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMRAg.png) shows). Bows and dots represent syllables (dot - 1 letter syllable, bow - 2 letter syllable). The painting is provided by dragging of green slider.

There is a variant of getting syllable position with the help of GlobalKey. I use the method List.generate for creating numerous GlobalKeys but get the exception Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey. How can help me to resolve this task?

**There is method for creating Row of Columns which include letter and bow or dot**.

```
List<Widget> createDotAndBows(String sentence, List<GlobalKey> keys) {
DetailedScreenBloc _bloc = DetailedScreenBloc();
List<String> syllablesRow = [];
List<Widget> dotAndBows = [];
List<String> splittedText = sentence.split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < splittedText.length; i++) {
  syllablesRow.addAll(_bloc.syllables(splittedText[i]));
}
_syllablesTotal.add(syllablesRow.length);
for (int index = 0; index < syllablesRow.length; index++) {
  dotAndBows.add(
    (syllablesRow[index] != ' ')
        ? IntrinsicWidth(
            key: keys[index],
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: FairyTaleSizes.tinyPadding4,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      syllablesRow[index],
                      style: FairyTaleStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(22),
                        color: FairyTaleColors.fullBlack,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  (_bloc.getSyllableType(syllablesRow[index]) == 2)
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: FairyTaleSizes.theMostTinyPadding2,
                          ),
                          child: CustomPaint(
                            painter: BowPainter(),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Container(
                                height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : (_bloc.getSyllableType(syllablesRow[index]) == 1)
                          ? Center(
                              child: Container(
                                height: getProportionateScreenHeight(23),
                                width: getProportionateScreenHeight(23),
                                decoration:
                                    const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: FairyTaleColors.fullBlack),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Text(
            '   ',
            key: keys[index],
          ),
  );
}
return dotAndBows;
```

}

**This is the implementation of the method above in UI**

```
    class DetailedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? detailedBanner;
  final List<String>? fullText;

  const DetailedScreen({this.detailedBanner, this.fullText});

  @override
  State<DetailedScreen> createState() => _DetailedScreenState();
}

class _DetailedScreenState extends State<DetailedScreen> {
  final ItemScrollController _itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener _itemPositionsListener = ItemPositionsListener.create();
  int currentIndex = 1;
  final _bloc = DetailedScreenBloc();
  List<GlobalKey> keysList = [];
  final GlobalKey _sliderKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _bloc.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: FairyTaleColors.lightGold,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 2,
                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: Image.asset(widget.detailedBanner ?? '').image,
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: ArrowWidget(
                              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(84),
                              width: getProportionateScreenWidth(36),
                              isForward: false,
                              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          StreamBuilder<bool>(
                              stream: _bloc.isVoiceOnStream,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                bool? _isVoiceOn = snapshot.data;
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: FairyTaleSizes.bigHorizontalPadding36,
                                  ),
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    child: VoiceSwitcher(
                                        isVoiceOn: _isVoiceOn,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (_isVoiceOn != null && _isVoiceOn) {
                                            _bloc.switchVoice(false);
                                          } else {
                                            _bloc.switchVoice(true);
                                          }
                                        }),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: FairyTaleSizes.middleHorizontalPadding22,
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        StreamBuilder<int>(
                            stream: _bloc.syllablesTotalStream,
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: FairyTaleSizes.twoHundredPadding216,
                                  ),
                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemScrollController: _itemScrollController,
                                  itemPositionsListener: _itemPositionsListener,
                                  itemCount: widget.fullText!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                    int total = snapshot.data ?? 0;
                                    keysList.addAll(
                                      List.generate(
                                        total,
                                        (index) => GlobalKey(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                    print('$index - $keysList');
                                    return Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        bottom: FairyTaleSizes.itemsMassivePadding140,
                                      ),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: _bloc.createDotAndBows(
                                          widget.fullText![index],
                                          keysList,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                        StreamBuilder<double>(
                            initialData: 0.0,
                            stream: _bloc.shadowPositionStream,
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              double _position = snapshot.data ?? 0.0;
                              return Positioned(
                                left: _position,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: FairyTaleColors.lightGold.withOpacity(0.9),
                                  height: getProportionateScreenWidth(23),
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                        StreamBuilder<List>(
                            stream: CombineLatestStream.list([
                              _bloc.sliderValueStream,
                              _bloc.shadowPositionStream,
                            ]),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              double _sliderValue = snapshot.data?[0] ?? 0.0;
                              double _shadowPosition = snapshot.data?[1] ?? 0.0;
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: FairyTaleSizes.hundredPadding100,
                                  horizontal: FairyTaleSizes.massivePadding64,
                                ),
                                child: SliderTheme(
                                  data: const SliderThemeData(
                                    trackShape: GradientRectSliderTrackShape(),
                                    trackHeight: 14.0,
                                    thumbShape: GradientSliderThumbShape(
                                      enabledThumbRadius: 16,
                                      pressedElevation: 5.1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Slider(
                                    key: _sliderKey,
                                    min: 0.0,
                                    max: 200.0,
                                    value: _sliderValue,
                                    inactiveColor: FairyTaleColors.inactiveGrey,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      _sliderValue = value;
                                      _shadowPosition = value * 4.5;
                                      _bloc.changeSliderValue(_sliderValue);
                                      _bloc.stepBySyllable(keysList);
                                      // _bloc.changeShadowPosition(_shadowPosition);
                                    },
                                    onChangeEnd: (value) {
                                      if (value == 200) {
                                        keysList.clear();
                                        _bloc.changeSliderValue(0.0);
                                        _shadowPosition = 0;
                                        _bloc.scrollString(_itemScrollController, currentIndex);
                                        _bloc.changeShadowPosition(0.0);
                                        currentIndex++;
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there is other way. What kind of item are you talking about? Can you provide some code or illustration?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamónCondezo it's Row of Columns. Every Column consists of letter and icon(Column: children[Text, Icon]). And I would like to find out the width in pixels every of current Column in this Row.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamónCondezo I've added the description, some code and illustration. Can you help me?